# How to merge a character vector conditional on cells of a numerical vector?

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following character vector **A**:

```
A <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
```

And the following numerical vector **B**:

```
B <- c(1,4,6)
```

I want to create a third character vector **C**, which merges **A** using **B**, such that:

```
C <- c("abc", "de", "fgh")
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
C <- mapply(function(x1, x2){
                 paste(A[x1:x2], collapse="")
             }, 
             x1=B, 
             x2=c(B[-1]-1, length(A))
            )

C
#[1] "abc" "de"  "fgh"
```

`C` is constructed by applying `paste` with `collapse` to each subset of `A` defined by the indices given by `B` for each "first index", on one hand, and `c(B[-1]-1, length(A))` (here `c(3, 5, 8)`) for each "second index" on the other hand.

Answer (score 2):

Another, similar, idea:

```
substring(paste(A, collapse = ""), B, c(B[-1] - 1, length(A)))
#[1] "abc" "de"  "fgh"
```

Comment: nice one (+1) I didn't know you could put vectors for `start` and `stop`